# Can Redcap tally responses?

Tags: redcap

I have a matrix with three different possible responses, N, E, or C.  Can Redcap tally the number of "N" responses?

I'm fairly new to redcap and don't necessarily know what to try.  I've tried if/then statements, but they're getting complicated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming N, E and C are the labels of the choices in a matrix of radio fields (feel free to correct my assumptions) so, something like this:

[image]

Where N is coded 1, E is 2 and C is 3.

To count the number of individual fields in which N, E and C were selected, then you would create three different calculated fields, `[count_n]`, `[count_e]` and `[count_c]`, that have these calculation equations:

[count_n]:
`sum(if([q1]='1',1,0), if([q2]='1',1,0), if([q3]='1',1,0))`

[count_e]:
`sum(if([q1]='2',1,0), if([q2]='2',1,0), if([q3]='2',1,0))`

[count_c]:
`sum(if([q1]='3',1,0), if([q2]='3',1,0), if([q3]='3',1,0))`

This will produce the following:

[image]

Again, let me know if I've got your requirements wrong.

Comment: This is awesome!  Exactly what I needed!  Thank you so much!

Comment: @JMicek Glad I could help! Please consider 'accepting' this answer.